# Twitter rate limits question

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been reading Twitter's documentation on this but I'm a bit confused because I'm new to both the API and oauth. If I get a user to login to Twitter using oAuth does that mean that the rate limit would be 350 requests for their account and not my application? In other words, is the rate limiting applied to each account used individually or 350 for my application?

Comment: This is actually a dupe of a question I asked last year and probably many people have asked, good question :) but a dupe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Rate limit , who's mine or my users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766066/twitter-rate-limit-whos-mine-or-my-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/faq):

> **Are rate limits per user, per computer or per application?**
>
> Rate limits apply in different ways. Some methods are rate limited
>   whilst others are fair use limited. In the majority of methods GET
>   (read) requests are rate limited and POST (write) methods are not. You
>   should check the rate limited section of the documentation for the
>   method you want to use to make sure.
>
> We apply requests to rate limits in the following ways:
>
> - Rate limits for authenticated requests are applied to the user.
> - Rate limits for unauthenticated requests are applied to the IP that
>     we see.
>
> This means applications share the unauthenticated rate limit AND the
>   authenticated limit. The application being used makes no difference so
>   switching between multiple clients on the same IP offers no rate limit
>   advantage – they will all share the same remaining requests.
>
> Multiple user accounts in a Twitter client each have their own user
>   rate limit but share the unauthenticated requests.
>
> Search has it's own rate limit and as all requests are anonymous it
>   applies to the IP we see. This means all users on the same IP share
>   the search rate limit.

This means that every request which you'll be doing for an authenticated user (OAuth) will check this user's rate limit, while any general non authenticated request you'll make will check your application's IP rate limit.

Comment: Can every general non auth'd request also be made on the users behalf?

Comment: I guess this depends on where your application is located: if installed on your server (web app) then your IP will be seen by Twitter and you will be the one "billed". If it is a desktop app, then the end-user's IP address will be the one seen by Twitter and this IP will be billed instead.

Answer (score 0):

- Javascript, Client side request - users rate limit.
- Serverside request - web applications rate limit.
- Client application using streaming API - no rate limit (technically
  not true, but a rate limit that you won't need to worry about because
  your limited in another way based on the information you track
  instead and the stream updates you at a limit below the cap)

for more, look at the duplicate question, the FAQ link that was posted, and the rate limiting doc,

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting